# What User info that should be saved in the application data base

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-ad-b2c

I'm implementing authentification for a Xamarin application using Azure B2C.
To signup user we will need the user firstname, last name and his email.
later in the application the user will be asked to add his address and his user photo.
Should I add the user address and photo to be saved in the B2C or I should keep them saved in the application data base?
what is the user unique identifier that I should share between B2C and application data base? should I use the email or the userId?

Comment: the answers to these questions depend on your application's specific requirements.  We can't answer them for you.

Comment: Thanks Jason, could you provide more clarification and guide how I cold make the choice? what about the second question what is the user unique identifier that I should share between B2C and application data base? should I use the email or the userId?

Comment: Use the objectId.

Answer (score 0):

In the auth token you receive back from Azure AD, you have an object ID that is unique to each user.

The B2C token is slightly different to the regular AD token, you don't get back all the values listed in the Token Reference (e.g. Groups, you have to query for these separately), but you will get the object ID that you can then use to lookup your DB.

Please visit here for further [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-tokens).

You can decode your JWT token here to see what you get back: https://jwt.io/

Hope it helps.

Comment: What if I'm going to use local authentication with google and facebook providers. suppose we have the same user that will login each time using one of the available providers but all the three accounts are sharing the same email address. in this case using the objectID will cause to create three separate users in the application backend.